# Cordova Android app POST request return status 0

Tags: android, cordova, cross-domain, html-framework-7

I hope this will not be marked as duplicate, since I can't find the answer anywhere.

The main problem here is that my **cordova android application returns status 0.**

I created a simple android app that ask for a POST request and displays the request status, in a locally hosted PHP server with CORS enabled.

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-type: application/json');
 ...
```

Since I am using an emulator, I used `10.0.2.2` and local IP of my computer for this testing. As you can see in the image, it is displaying the IP and the **0** status:

Here are my tests in different environments:
Sorry I'm new so I can't post images.

[Android app in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bekIq.png)

[Application in emulator's browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIWw1.png)

[Application in local browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Fsz.png)

Here is my `config.xml`

```
<access origin="*" />
<content src="index.html" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Here is my meta tag for Content-Security-Policy in my HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: content:">
```

Here are my AndroidManifests.xml that contains`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

`cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="io.framework7.myapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     </application>
 </manifest>
```

Another Android manifest from `cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.apache.cordova" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
</manifest>
```

cordova version: `11.0.0`

framework7 CLI: `5.1.5`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just comment out the metatag totally and test, but do that only for debugging purpose. Status 0 means your XHR request is getting cancelled.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but sadly it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: got your problem then, you need to modify the android manifest file add this line to your application tag `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` eg : `<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>` ,android is not allowing http, only https is allowed in cordova 10+

Comment: Hi, actually I already added that one, will update the question.